# How to set the background color of JFrame to its blank value?

Tags: java, swing

I want to use a 'Clear' button to clear the background color of a `JFrame` after using a 'color' button to add color to the background. Everything I've been able to find tells me how to change the value to a different color but not how to remove it.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ColorFrame extends JFrame {
    JButton red, green, blue, clear;
    
    public ColorFrame() {
        super("ColorFrame");
        
        setSize(322, 122);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout(); 
        setLayout(flo);
        red = new JButton ("Red");
        add(red);
        green = new JButton ("Green");
        add(green);
        blue = new JButton("Blue");
        add(blue);
        clear = new JButton("Clear");
        add(clear);
    
        ActionListener act = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
                if(event.getSource() == red) {
                    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
                }
                if(event.getSource() == green) {
                    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                }
                if(event.getSource() == blue) {
                    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                }   
                if(event.getSource() == clear) {
                    //clear background color
                }
            }
        };

        red.addActionListener(act);
        green.addActionListener(act);
        blue.addActionListener(act);
        clear.addActionListener(act);

        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String arguments[]) {
        new ColorFrame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Everything I've been able to find tells me how to change the value to a different color but not how to remove it.*" - This is because you shouldn't. Even the "default" background color is a color and I think you should not try to "remove" it in any way.

You can of course set the background color of the `JFrame` (or more specifically, the frame's content pane) back to its default value.
For this, you can use one of two approaches:

**1. Simply save the default value before you modify it**

```java
public class ColorFrame extends JFrame {
    JButton red, green, blue, clear;
    Color defaultColor;

    ...

    ActionListener yourListener = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
            // save the frame background default value before changing it
            defaultColor = getContentPane().getBackground();
            // modify the color as needed and use the stored default later as needed
```

**2. Retrieve the default background color from the UIManager**

Each swing component's default properties are stored in the `UIManager`, specific to each look and feel. Knowing this, you can easily retrieve these default values as needed:

```java
Color defaultColor = UIManager.getColor("Panel.background");
getContentPane().setBackground(defaultColor);
```

---

Some additional considerations regarding your code:

- Use [`Action`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)s or at least separate `ActionListener`s if you want different behavior for each button. Having a shared `ActionListener` which then checks from which component the action was fired from is not recommended.
- Don't use `setSize()`. Instead, let the `LayoutManager` size the components and frame for you by calling `pack()` on the `JFrame` after adding all components.
- Avoid extending `JFrame` if there is no need to. (I currently see no need to in your code, since you don't fundamentally change the default behaviour of the `JFrame`)

Comment: Thank you, this was quite helpful and resolved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

Set the background to no color, i.e. null:

```
getContentPane().setBackground(null);
```

Comment: This works, I had tried this yesterday and returned error but I must have mistyped it. Thanks!